# How to make toolbar/appbar scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-toolbar

I saw this app, which I thought to be very clean and well designed, so I tried using it to practice, but I had some issues.

They used a collapsing toolbar, which they made seamless with the status bar, but the toolbar doesn't collapse when scrolled, it just scrolls like a regular `view`, or `composeable` in jetpack compose.

And the toolbar scrolls when you swipe on it.

Here's an Image of it;
[image]

**The issue I'm facing now is;**

- The collapsing toolbar doesn't scroll when I swipe **on it**, I tried giving the collapsing toolbar a `.verticalScrollState`, but it crashes the app.
- And Also, when I scroll the elements (views) at the bottom of my App (which is the only side that scrolls, because the toolbar above doesn't respond), I don't get the same motion I get from the original App, mine appears as though the elements at the bottom is overlapping the toolbar, but I want everything to scroll upwards seamlessly.

So please **(1)** How do I make the collapsing toolbar scrollable, 
**(11)** How do I make everything scroll upwards seamlessly.

Here's my Collapsing toolbar code;

first I added a the gradle dependency

```
implementation "me.onebone:toolbar-compose:2.3.2"
```

```
@Composable
fun ContactCollapsingToolbar(
    onContactsCardClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    val collapsingToolbarState = rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState()

    CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        state = collapsingToolbarState,
        scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.EnterAlwaysCollapsed,
        toolbar = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .pin()
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                                White
                            )
                        )
                    )
            )

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.fc4_self_massage),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomEnd = 45.dp))
                //alpha =
            )

            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.contact_categories),
                style = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary) + MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )

        }
    ) {

        ContactsContentScreen(onContactsCardClick)

    }

}
```

I'll sinerely appreciate any help, whether code, instructions, or directing me somewhere.

Thanks to you in advance.

Comment: Adding a scroll to toolbar brings an issue of distinguish scroll from plain tap. If you still want it, you could try to put Toolbar and the rest of the code into the same container, e.g. ```ConstraintLayout```, and altogether will be hosted inside a ```ScrollView``` (ScrollView requires a single child)

Comment: For the 2nd issue, I think, you have to write your own component. It's a general behaviour for multiple scrolling elements within each other. I don't think there is a know solution except ```NestedScrollView``` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView